# How to insert nested json in Datatables javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, datatables

In response from controller in ajax I'm getting a string array, which I m converting to javascript array
The problem is that the array contains a nested json array
which I need to plot on jquery DataTables.
For normal Jsons it is working but if the Json is nested it is not working.

How to to implement this?

What I'm trying to do is

making a array of data and title and pushing that array to columns of DataTables

But this only works for normal json
but not for nested json array.

This is my nested Json Example:-

```
//SAMPLE JSON { "id": "1951-4", "example": { "1": [ 6721 ], "2": [ 6722 ] } }
```

Need to represent DataTable of the above sample json Object..

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/searchData/",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#resultLoader").show();
    },
    success: function (result) {
        var resultArray = JSON.parse(result);
        var my_columns = [];
        var my_item = {};
        var nestedcolumns = [];
        $.each(resultArray[0], function (key, value) {
            var my_item = {};
            if (typeof value === "object") {
                $.each(value, function (key, value) {
                    var nestedItem = {};
                    nestedItem.data = key;
                    nestedItem.title = key;
                    nestedcolumns.push(nestedItem);
                    my_item.data = nestedcolumns;
                });
            } else {
                my_item.data = key;
            }
            my_item.title = key;
            my_columns.push(my_item);
        });
        $("#example").show();
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
                data: resultArray,
                "columns": my_columns
            });
    },
    complete: function () {
        $("#resultLoader").hide();
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log("Error", error);
    }
});
```

Error:

> DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter
>   '[object Object],[object Object]' for row 0, column 1. For more
>   information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: And, by the way, your approach to populate DataTable from AJAX response is **all wrong** - it raises all sorts of issues related to async AJAX nature and disables you from benefiting all the wonderful DataTables API methods. Instead, you should use DataTables option [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)

Comment: it is not that clear from your code, what exactly you want to achieve: what the contents of those two rows should appear like.